# TikTok icon in LaTeX

Tags: packages, logos

Is there a package (like FontAwesome or academicons) that provides the TikTok logo in similar fashion to the Twitter or Github icons in FontAwesome?

Comment: You can always use a small image (something like `\includegraphics[height=1ex]{tiktoklogo}`) instead of a character from an icon font. Of course this requires that you get the image file from somewhere, but for Tiktok that is easy to find, also in vector format that looks good when zoomed.

Comment: Here there is a related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66933650/how-can-i-replicate-the-tiktok-logo-in-fontawesome-with-colors

Answer (score 3):

With an up-to-date TeX installation (you might have to update first), you can just use the TikTok icon from the `fontawesome5` package. This works with all common engines (LaTeX, pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX have been tested, others should work too):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
TikTok: \faTiktok
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this morning to 1:30 pm (GMT+1) I have done an update on MikTeX and there is not your package. Now I'm trying but I have not found the package. +1. The guide there is on ctan.

Answer (score 2):

I add simply the link of *tiktok* symbol `\symbol{"F97B}` compiling with `XeLaTeX` for example: https://github.com/liweitianux/resume/blob/master/fontawesome5/fontawesome5.sty where you can found the symbol

```
row 1309: \expandafter\def\csname faicon@tiktok\endcsname{\symbol{"F97B}}
row 3885: \def\faTiktok{{\FontAwesomeBrands\csname faicon@tiktok\endcsname}}
```

Comment: So you can also just use `\faTiktok`.

Comment: In about 24 hours you can just (update your TeX installation and then) use `\usepackage{fontawesome5}` and then use `\faTiktok`.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Hi, from Sicily. Thank you very much for your advice and for your fantastic fontawesome5 package. You think that I have not any social on my smartphone :-)