# Adjust the code to get TikTok symbol

Tags: symbols, definition, fontawesome5

This question it is related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595714/tiktok-icon-in-latex).

Considering the link of my answer where there are the conditions to have the tiktok symbol https://github.com/liweitianux/resume/blob/master/fontawesome5/fontawesome5.sty
and considering that this MWE not works:

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
  \usepackage{fontawesome5} 
  \expandafter\def\csname faicon@tiktok\endcsname{\symbol{"F97B}} 
  \def\faTiktok{{\FontAwesomeBrands\csname faicon@tiktok\endcsname}}
  \begin{document}
  \faTikTok
  \end{document}
```

> Which way or some technique should be used to get the TikTok symbol?

Comment: I have no idea really, but a new version of `fontawesome5` was out yesterday, so it should arrive very soon on TeX Live and MiKTeX.

Comment: @Bernard Mine was just a curiosity how works the code of my MWE: :-)

Comment: It's the same I saw on GitHub, but perhaps your version of the fonts does not have tiktok?

Comment: @Bernard Bohhh..I not know this :-( I'm sorry.

Comment: The version on my system, which dates back to last year, doesn't have its icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three issues:

1. A simple typo: You define `\faTiktok` (with a lowercase `t`), but use `\faTikTok` (with a capital `T`)
2. In a standard TeX installation, `\usepackage{fontawesome5}` loads my `fontawesome5` package and not Weitian Li's `fontawesome5` package (the one you linked to). The command `\FontAwesomeBrands` is only available in Weitian Li's package.
3. If you haven't installed an updated version of Font Awesome manually and still have the old version of the package installed, then the font doesn't contain the glyph anyway.

So what can you do to make `\faTiktok` available? (Assuming that installing the updated version of the LaTeX package isn't an option, e.g. since it isn't yet packaged in your distribution.)

1. Download the latest font files from [the Font Awesome GitHub repo](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/otfs). (For TikTok you only need the `Font Awesome 5 Brands-Regular-400.otf` file, but it's best to download all three)
2. Rename the files to remove all the spaces from their names. So e.g. `Font Awesome 5 Brands-Regular-400.otf` becomes `FontAwesome5Brands-Regular-400.otf`. (This is needed to get the same filenames as used by the package, as packages on CTAN can not contain files with spaces)
3. Copy the three files into a directory where your TeX system expects OpenType fonts, e.g. the directory of your TeX document or `~/texmf/fonts/opentype/fontawesome5/` (where `~/texmf` should be substituted with a texmf root directory on your system)
4. Now both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX should be able to run

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
   \usepackage{fontawesome5}
   \begin{document}
   \faTikTok
   \end{document}
   ```

   You do *not* have to define `\faTiktok`, the package automatically extracts the names of all defined icons from the font file and makes them available.

This does not work for pdfLaTeX. The icons can only be used for pdfLaTeX after the package is updated. If you know that there is a new FontAwesome version but the LaTeX package isn't updated yet, feel free to ping me by mail. (The address can be found in the package documentation.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent explanation.